# Is there some way that we can help new users to add EXIF data to their photo?

Tags: feature-request

Often you have a user uploading a photo with a question, but then no metadata is included (as that's stripped by imgur). Other users have then to ask what settings were used, creating a back-and-forth until (hopefully) the right EXIF data is found by the question asker.

Sites exist (e.g.: https://exifinfo.org/ ) that can automatically extract EXIF data from a photo. Is there some way that we can alter the photo upload dialog such that it passes an uploaded photo through an EXIF service first, then pastes relevant EXIF fields in the question before uploading the actual image to imgur?

Or is this too much work for the problem it's trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** I opened a feature request at Meta-SE for this feature: [Site-specific need for image uploader to paste EXIF exposure information into post along with image URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360895/175991)

---

You have a great idea. However, the issues that immediately come to mind are:

1. This would almost certainly require a change to the common Stack Exchange code's image upload feature, and probably triggered based on the Stack subdomain (i.e., `photo.stackexchange.com` vs. other Stacks). It's something that the other Stacks probably would want off by default, but we would want on by default.
2. External EXIF service vs. self-hosted (Stack Exchange network): I'm sure Stack Exchange's legal team would want a service agreement, specifying terms regarding privacy, data retention, service level assurance, etc. It seems to me that it's probably better to rely on a self-hosted EXIF solution (i.e., server-side script, CGI, whatever). It's logically similar to server-side ImageMagick various uses.

Comment: Thanks for going into the rabbit hole of opening a feature request on Meta-SE!

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke =) It's a learning process for me. Got lots of good suggestions over there.

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: this was my original answer, based on misreading the question. I had deleted it when MichaelC noted I wasn't addressing your question, but I later undeleted it in order to preserve the info about Imgur's EXIF policy, in case that comes up in discussion later.)*

Based on [this answer to a Meta Stack Exchange question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266391/is-exif-data-removed-from-uploaded-se-pictures) (at least as of 2015), nothing will probably change:

> Here is a reply from imgur userecho question [Where is the EXIF data?](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/42809-where-is-the-exif-data/) :
>
> > This is one of the features of the service. exif data is removed because the images are shared publicly and the developer does not want hidden information to leak accidentally by users who might have no idea what exif information is stored in the photos. I do not think there is any setting available on imgur platform that retains the data if you so desire.
>
> Here is [reply](https://imgur.userecho.com/topic/60879-exif/) from Alan Schaaf (Founder of imgur):
>
> > Sorry, but exif data is striped on purpose to keep the anonymity of the uploader. This will not change.

Comment: I think what the OP is suggesting is extracting the EXIF info (or at least the high points like ISO, Tv, Av, FL, etc.) to a separate text file that can be copied/pasted to the question separately from the process of uploading the actual image via imgur?

Comment: @MichaelC Thanks for encouraging me to re-read the question; you're absolutely right. I deleted this answer because it was off-base, and also seemingly dismissive or discouraging of what Saaru was trying to achieve. So to advocate for the site, I opened up a feature request in [meta.se] as noted in my other answer. Thanks for turning me onto the right path here. =)

Comment: I made a couple of [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360895/site-specific-need-for-image-uploader-to-paste-exif-exposure-information-into-po#comment1204261_360895) on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360895/site-specific-need-for-image-uploader-to-paste-exif-exposure-information-into-po#comment1204289_360895) about the technical implementation of this Feature; that wouldn't break anything, nor be particularly complicated. --- I see that my idea of Featuring this question has lead to a few more views and votes, these past two weeks; a little short of "popular".

Comment: @Rob "popular" is relative on sites with declining participation. =)

Comment: Yes "participation" is the problem, because you get [20K visits per day](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic); which is way more than many other sites, where one might think that their subject matter is popular. --- I think you lost one vote in the last hour, the views and votes simply don't scream (or whisper): "We want this!". --- Both [QC.SE](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) and [OR.SE](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions) have far fewer visitors, yet get "relatively" greater views and votes. --- Lethargy is the problem.

Comment: @Rob I don't understand, what is your mission? I requested a feature at Meta-SE. You made multiple comments over there making non-sequitur suggestions (i.e., greasemonkey/tampermonkey script), and seemingly talking down the idea because... it didn't receive 20 upvotes at Meta-PSE? It's a feature **request**. I even explained in a comment that I don't expect it to be implemented (I'm sure there are many higher-priority features and issues for SE). But if a request isn't made/documented, it has 0% chance of implementation. So why are you now over here adding nothing to the conversation? You seem

Comment: to want to both make sure you get credit for suggesting `featured` tag here (which I thanked you for over at MSE), and simultaneously point out that the feature request isn't worthy because PSE members don't participate very actively at Meta-PSE. Great, good, you've made your point. Rather than neg the effort to improve things for PSE, why not just comment on the best or most likely feasible implementation over at the Meta-SE post, suggest unforeseen consequences, or any other productive contribution.

Comment: @scottbb I think you've misremembered the conversation, I told you that I am a supporter of the idea. If you've not understood what's being said that gives me pause.

Comment: @Rob If I misunderstood, then I am wrong. But you gave me the most pushback, suggested that I was too early asking for the feature request, and then explained a whole bunch of negative rationale (that you deleted, so I can't refer to it). And I don't see how your points _here_ (both at Meta-PSE, and _to this particular non-answer_ I gave) help or support the feature request.